# Best method to retrive data from SQL DB in Android

Tags: android, asp.net, sql, web-services

I am using SOAP method to retrive data from SQL Database in Android App using Asp.NET Webservice.
I have also seen JSON method for this but it was using php.
Which is the best method ??? I am having Windows Server and SQL Database so I am gonna to use Asp.NET web service only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have SqlServer means U could go for **asp.Net Json Webservices** . Json is very easy to parse and Myself also using the .net webservice with json format only.

Parsing is so fast as well as easy for mobile developers

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And then In Webserice add the following method.

**Json Array-Object** mostly we ll use

```
     [WebMethod]
     [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
     public static string GenerateTopicListToJSon()
            {
                try

                {

                    //Do ur query in GetMethod() to retrieve from DB     
                    List<Employee> lstEmployee = GetMethod();
                    var topic = from t in lstEmployee
                                select new
                                {
                                    Name= t.TopicID,
                                    Company = t.Company,
                                    Address = t.Address,
                        Phone = t.Phone,
                                    Country = t.Country

                                };


                    var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    return oSerializer.Serialize(topic);

                }
```

Hope it helps u buddy..

Cheers.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you give me some sample code as I am new to Android.

Comment: U use this URL ..http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: where to pass query to retrieve data ?

Comment: can you give me any real time example ? I am gonna to use it first time so I am not able to understand it.

Comment: Buddy i gave u the example code from my live site.. First u gonna retrieve from db as a generic list . Then use my web service . To get DB list as a generic u have lot of options buddy..

Comment: Ya fine. But this is the web service.. Nothing is big till u know keep rock it.. All the best...